# How JPA Lock annotation works before entity is saved?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have Lock annotation in my Repository class.

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
Optional<Author> findByName(String name);
```

Does Lock work only with an entity existing in DB? What will happen if I call this method in multiple threads for not existing entity in DB?

For example author with name "Pushkin" is not in db. And a few threads call this method, check that this author is not in db and try to create record and save. Please explain to me what will happen? Will @Lock work correct?

Comment: `@Lock` annotation causes HBN to add [`for update` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) to select statement, DB in turn places row-level lock on rows returned to client (`Java` in your case), so, this locking technique affects existing rows only.